# How to remove select2 from dom

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Say we have a simple `select2` list:

```
<select id="e1">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Initiated like:

```
$("#e1").select2();
```

How can I remove `select2` and return it to a regular dropdown? I can't find any examples or entry in documentation.

Something like:

```
$("#e1").select2('remove');
```

would be nice.

Comment: Link to docs: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#event-unbinding

Comment: Should be $('#elm').select2( 'destroy' ); [Reference](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#destroying-the-select2-control)

Comment: Selectize is better than select2 https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ i recommend it.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You need to use `destroy` method on select2. See the [Documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#e14_destroy)

i.e

```
 $("#e1").select2('destroy');
```

Comment: Link has changed (they replaced it with docs for 4.0 which are currently woefully incomplete). Passing explanation can be found here: http://select2.github.io/select2/#lifecycle

Answer (score 15):

That work for me!

```
var $select = $('.select2').select2();
//console.log($select);
$select.each(function(i,item){
  //console.log(item);
  $(item).select2("destroy");
});
```

Comment: Worked for me, to destroy every select2 instance

Comment: Important thing is that if you want to destroy select2 then make sure you have added it first, if your select input is not has select2 then destroy will not work.

Comment: @always-a-learner There is a pretty nice tweak for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746804/818628. Btw you dont need the each loop, works without it.

Answer (score 5):

Version 4.0

```
$element.data('select2').destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".select2").select2('destroy');
$(".select2").val('Your Value');
$('.select2').each(function () {
    $(this).select2({ dropdownParent: $(this).parent() });
});
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.